# How to display the number of lines, words and characters in separate lines?

Tags: command-line, wc

I want to display the number of lines, words and characters, in a file, in separate lines?
I don't know anymore than using `wc filename` for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tr`:

```
wc filename | tr ' ' '\n'
```

, or if you just want the numbers:

```
wc filename | tr ' ' '\n' | head -3
```

Comment: Great !! Thanks. Can you help me to extract just lines 2-4. I can pipe the output in the chain of `head` and `tail` but is there any single command operation possible?

Comment: Or I should ask it as a separate question if you want another +10. :)

Comment: @Gaurav `wc filename | tr ' ' '\n' | tail -3` no need for a seperate question, but you can accept this answer of course (hint, hint). This only works if the filename has contains no spaces or other "special" characters (but if it did line number 4 would not be so interesting anyway).

Comment: @Anthon: You can use `wc < filename` to prevent filename from being printed to output.

Comment: @gnouc I always forget that, thanks for reminding. But for what the OP commented later (just print word & byte count + filename (lines 2-4)), that would not help.

Comment: That won't work in many cases with most `wc` implementations. For instance, with GNU `wc`, if all three numbers are not expressed with the same number of digits, then there will be additional spaces.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas For the original question you are right. By accident, for just getting the word-count, byte-count and filename (without spaces) as the OP later asked, the `wc filename | tr ' ' '\n' | tail -3` works, as I don't think you will get more than one space between the word- and byte-count numbers and the byte-count and filename (as the byte-count is always among the longest of the three numbers).

Answer (score 2):

I like using `xargs -n XX` to have `XX` items per line.

See:

```
$ wc a
 3  5 21 a
$ wc < a
 3  5 21
$ wc < a | xargs -n 1
3
5
21
```

Answer (score 2):

```
printf %d\\n $(wc <file)
```

That will insert a newline between each of `printf`'s arguments, which, when split on a default `$IFS` are the spaces between `wc`'s output.

For example:

```
printf %d\\n $(wc <<< $(seq -s" some splitter $IFS" 100))
100
298
1975
```

Comment: Cleanest solution thank you

Answer (score 1):

With shells with support for process substitution (ksh, zsh, bash), you could do something like:

```
read line word byte < <(wc < file)
echo "file has $line lines, $word words and $byte bytes"
```

With AT&T ksh or zsh,

```
wc < file | read line word byte
```

should also work.